# Is it possible to move windows to other disk?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems

Recently I buy a laptop that using HDD, include Windows 10 Home. Now, I want to buy new SSD to increase my laptop performance. Is it possible to move the OS to new disk? Because I do not have the CD, and I won't to use cracking OS

Comment: There are several free disk cloning softwares that are just for that purpose. I use Macrium Reflect Free for this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible and fairly easy, you'd need a *disk cloning* software and there are plenty available, I personally prefer [Easeus Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html) for it's UI.
It has a free version that lets you migrate your OS to a different disk.

1. [Follow this tutorial to transfer your Windows to your SSD](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-guide/migrate-os-to-ssd.html)
2. Boot into your BIOS (process depends on your manufacturer) and change your Boot sequence to make sure your SSD is now first in that sequence.
3. Once you boot with your SSD, you can safely remove OS files from your old HDD.